# How to use QWS_MOUSE_PROTO inside code in Qt

Tags: qt, mouseevent

I am using QT to make an application for Embedded linux device. When I started my application, mouse & keyboard was not working. From searching about this problem, I came to know that we need to run below command before starting the application:

```
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO="USB:/dev/input/event-mouse"
export QWS_KEYBOARD="USB:/dev/input/event-keyboard"
```

After running above commands, I was able to use mouse and keyboard in my application. But this looks a bit odd because whenever I need to run my application, I have to run those commands. Also I will be setting my application to auto run after the boot so in that case I won't be able to run those commands. So I was wondering if I can include these commands somewhere in my code so that they automatically run and then application starts. Can anyone please guide me here. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running your application, you could run a script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO="USB:/dev/input/event-mouse"
export QWS_KEYBOARD="USB:/dev/input/event-keyboard"
my_application
```

You can also set the environment variables inside of your application, before Qt is started. Use [`setenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html):

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  // Set default values if none are set.
  setenv("QWS_MOUSE_PROTO", "USB:/dev/input/event-mouse", 0);
  setenv("QWS_KEYBOARD", "USB:/dev/input/event-keyboard", 0);
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  ...
  return app.exec();
}
```

External `QWS_MOUSE_PROTO` and `QWS_KEYBOARD` will override the internal defaults since the `override` parameter is set to zero. This is the desired behavior.

Comment: Including everything in a script worked well but I don't know why it didnt worked when I included it inside the code.